# Zoom and plot only specific node for a given dendogram

Tags: r, hclust, dendextend

Hi suppose I generated a dendogram as such:

```
library(dendextend)
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
    select(mpg, cyl, disp) %>% 
    dist() %>% 
    hclust() %>% 
    as.dendrogram() -> dend

dend %>% 
    set("nodes_pch", 19)  %>% 
    set("nodes_cex", 0.7) %>% 
    set("nodes_col", "orange") %>% 
    plot()
```

I want to keep this dendogram but zoom in on one of the node and replot without rerunning the distance and hclust.  Is this possible  Here is an image of where I want to cut and replot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify the area in which you would like to zoom in using the `xlim` and `ylim` arguments in `plot`. For example, the node you are interested in plotting is found between x-axis positions 4 and 7 (position from left to right) and y-axis positions 0 and 10.

```
dend %>% 
  set("nodes_pch", 19)  %>% 
  set("nodes_cex", 0.7) %>% 
  set("nodes_col", "orange") %>% 
  plot(xlim = c(4,7),
       ylim = c(0,10))
```

[image: Zoomed Dendro]